# ¿Como construir sistemas lineales en python?

Tags: python

la verdad es que no tengo idea de como hacer estos sistemas en python y poder gratificarlos podrían decirme un código parecido de como se hace

```
y[n]=x[n−1]+3/8y[n−1]
y[n]=x[n]+0.8y[n−2]
y[n]=0.5x[n]+4/5y[n−1]
```

Pase por los sistemas la señal:
`x[n]=cos(π4⋅n)⋅u[n]`

graficar la entrada y salida de la misma

Comment: Hola @Avelino te recomiendo que revises esta página para evitar que tu pregunta sea cerrada https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Por otro lado existe una biblioteca para hacer gráficos en python, aquí puedes econtrar una guía para iniciar: https://pythonforundergradengineers.com/plotting-sin-cos-with-matplotlib.html Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

- Si buscas graficar ecuaciones te recomiendo usar *numpy* (librería de cálculo y métodos numéricos)
- *matplotlib* (generalmente para graficar).

Un ejemplo simple sería:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(-5,5,.1) 
# Con esto creamos una tira de numeros 
# entre el -5 y el 5 avanzando en .1 .
y = np.sin(x) 
plt.plot(x,y) #con esta y la siguiente linea graficamos y mostramos
plt.show()
```

[image: *f(x) = sin(x), x en rango de [-5,5] *]